# Adding column to query results in a larger result-set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got the following query which returns 13 rows in the result set.  If I uncomment `l.line_no` then the query returns 19 rows in the result set.  I've ran this multiple times over the past hour and have confirmed that the dataset is not changing.

Is there some key piece of SQL logic that I'm missing?  Based on my experience adding a column should not add rows.

```
select distinct
  -- l.line_no,
  l.item_no,
  l.Ord_no as ord_no,
  (select top 1
    pro_no
  from
    wsPKGShipment s
  where
    s.Shipment_No = max(p.Shipment_No)
  order by s.shipped_dt + s.shipped_tm desc) as pro_no
from
  wsPKGLin l
    join
  wsPKG p on p.PKG_ID = l.PKG_ID
where ltrim(l.Ord_no) = '<order number>'
```

Comment: Take out DISTINCT and see if the rows returned changes when you remove/add l.line_no

Comment: Good catch guys. I, uh... didn't realize I had a district clause in the query. That explains everything. Oops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must focus on the distinct clause of your query. If you had this example data:

```
c1 | c2 | c3
a  | a  | c
b  | b  | c
a  | a  | d
```

And you write:

```
select distinct c1, c2 from mytable
```

You will get just the distinct combinations of columns c1 and c2:

```
c1 | c2 
a  | a 
b  | b
```

But if you chage your query to:

```
select distinct c1, c2, c3 from mytable
```

You will show an additional record as a result of it's different from the previous 2 ones adding the new column:

```
   c1 | c2 | c3
    a  | a  | c
    b  | b  | c
    a  | a  | d
```

Answer (score 1):

`select distinct` applies to *all* the columns being selected.  If you add another column, then it also applies to that column.

Hence, the behavior is not at all surprising.  If you look at the 19 rows, you'll probably see 13 sets of values for all but `lineno`.